# Bold Matched search string in a AutoSuggestBox?

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm a little surprised to see that this isn't a feature of the AutoSuggestBox but, I'm trying to configure an AutoSuggestBox to bold any matched text from what gets pulled up.

So it would look like:
[ jay                  ]
          **jay**deflix
      **jay**deflixutil
           tommy**jay**

If anyone has sample code, I'll gladly look at it, but I'll even gladly take a pointer at what to dig into (I'm self-taught, so I'm used to digging, just my binggle-fu is coming up short on this one).

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion list is actually a `ListView` of [`AutoSuggestBox`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48870695/bold-matched-search-string-in-a-autosuggestbox). More details please see [AutoSuggestBox styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185404.aspx). To define a custom look for each item in the list, use the `ItemTemplate` property of `AutoSuggestBox`, for more details about this please check the [Text changed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/auto-suggest-box#create-an-auto-suggest-box) section.

The [`TextBlock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock) can be set with paticial bold text with [`<Run>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run) tag that you can try to use inside the template. For example:

```
<AutoSuggestBox
    x:Name="asb"
    ... >
    <AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock> 
                <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding QueryString}"></Run>
                <Run Text="{Binding DisplaySpare}"></Run>            
            </TextBlock> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </AutoSuggestBox.ItemTemplate>
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

For more about how to contact the string to display, set the display order and bind to `ItemsSource`  please try it yourself. This depends on the original source and your special requirements.